# Windows Phone viewport meta tag

Tags: windows-phone-7, viewport, meta-tags

I'm currently working on a mobile website. Everything is working fine on both iOS and Android, i'm however experiencing problems with the viewport meta tag on Windows Phone when trying to set the width of the viewport to 640px. I'm using :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640,user-scalable=no"/>
```

However it seems that whenever you are trying to set a viewport greater that 480px Windows phone automatically applies to default viewport (1024px).

Any Workaround ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't had much success with `<meta name="viewport">` and Windows Phone 7.5 unless I set `width` between 320 to 480 (inclusive). If I want to set it outside of that range it seems to just default to 320.

I tried just using **`<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="640">`** and that worked perfectly. It behaves like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640,user-scalable=no">`.

According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/11/22/the-ie-mobile-viewport-on-windows-phone-7.aspx) and [the article](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/14/managing-the-windows-phone-browser-viewport.aspx) linked to by in [Mikael Koskinen's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9242327/134014) the range should be 320 to 10,000 but I haven't been able to reproduce that.

Comment: My experience on Windows Phone 7.5 has been similar. I want a viewport width of 600, on a page where the main div is fixed at 600px wide, but using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=x">` where x > 480 results in the mobile IE using its default viewport width of 1024 pixels - the same as if you don't use the viewport meta tag at all. I didn't try the `MobileOptimized` workaround because I want the user to retain control of the zoom level, but it sounds like a good option for some.

Answer (score 1):

[The Windows Phone team blogged about Windows Phone browser viewport](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/14/managing-the-windows-phone-browser-viewport.aspx) some time ago. They don't have examples for widths' greater than 480 but maybe you can find some tips from there, like using the dynamic viewport sizing.

Note that the blog post applies to Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango) only.