# IE on WP7, initial-scale does not work

Tags: windows, viewport

I think I have to tap into the knowledge of stackoverflow again. :)

Let's say I got a website with a width of 500px. I want that website displayed on the internet explorer on a windows phone 7 as a whole, no horizontal scrolling possible. I thought giving the site a width of 500px and setting the viewport to 500 would do the job. On webkit browser that really work, but on the WP the viewport keeps the device-width, in my case 320px. That's why a horizontal scrolling is possible.

Code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500">
```

On Android for example, the site got zoomed out until the page fits the screen. Anybody an idea why the ie behaves differently? Any solution?

Best Regards,

Sy

PS: I'm using the WP7 Emulator. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Defining viewport width for diffent device resolutions is a really bad practice.
Try simple css mediaqueries for it like:

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
body{
width:100%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:500px){
body{
width: 500px;
margin:0 auto;
}
}
```

It will perfectly work on any device.
And add this ideal viewport meta tag in your web application.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width" />
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for my problem. It was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236376/windows-phone-viewport-meta-tag/17274452#17274452).
The solution is to use the meta tag `MobileOptimized` in addition to viewport. That works for me. :)

```
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="640">
```

Best Regards,

Sy